# Regex pattern to match {{....}}

Tags: regex

I try to write regex pattern "\{\{.*\}\}" to match tags "{{...}}". But it alway match all string below:

```
{{  shortcode('') }} abc {{ shortcode('') }}
```

Please help me correct pattern to match each tag only, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\{\{(.*?)\}\}
```

Using `?` will cause the match to stop at the first closing bracket.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: @JonnyHenly You are correct and approximately 10 seconds ahead of me.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: Many thanks, It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use capturing brackets around the text inside the tags. This will return the captured text.

`"\{\{([^{}]+)\}\}"`

[Example here](https://regex101.com/r/bI5bO4/3).

**Edit:** Updated to OP's requirements.

Comment: Does not work. This matches everything inside the outermost brackets.